# Center UIButton image with UIBarButtonItem on UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying (everything in XCode with Interface Builder) to create a UIButton with image adding it to UIToolbar, which makes it UIBarButtonItem (when click twice it shows the UIButton properties).

I have a `image@2x.png` image with size `64x88` (height is `88`, because in Retina it's the toolbar height). I'm not interested in non-retina screens. I added this image to UIButton setting `Mode` in `View` properties to `Center` (or `Aspect Fit`, it shouldn't really matter here; tried both, aswell).
 Set its size to `32x44` (44 height in builder). Then, dragged it to `UIToolbar`.

Now, I want to change the width of my button to make it larger, because I want to give user some more space to tap, also, I planned the toolbar background for that. And I want the image on this button to remain the same, but centered. But, when I try to resize the UIBarButtonItem, it actually scales the image, no matter what `Mode` is set.

That's what happens (I'm showing an actual dragging process):

[image]

However, if I change image **real** size to height 44, it works well. But 44 height looks ugly in Retina devices, so, what should I do?

Comment: I have a hard time following you. Some screenshots of what's going on would be really helpful.

Comment: @Scott, added the screenshot of what happens with its image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen. For the sake of argument, create two images, image.png and image@2x.png, and when setting the image of the button, select image.png in Xcode.

---

Alternatively, you can create a `UIView`-based `UIBarButtonItem` and have a `UIImageView` and a `UIButton`. This way, you have a more precise control over the image sizing.

Comment: Thanks, thought about this, but it means creating 2 times more images :( And storing them in program, useless kbs...

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer! I read about this way too, seems like such creation for 15 buttons having 3 subviews is going to be a hell for me :)

Comment: Best would be to just have the non-retina images. Such small images, compressed well in Photoshop (or anything else) would be very few KB together.

Comment: Well, creating non-retina images seems to be the only working way. Need to get used to it :) Thanks for helping!